# Linux TCP Socket: how to combined TCP server ACK and data in one packet?

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

After TCP connection established (3-way handshake done), I have this scenario

TCP Client:

> 1. sent packet with "AAA" to TCP Server, by write();
> 2. wait to read "BBB" from TCP server, by read().

TCP Server:

> 1. wait to read "AAA" from TCP client, by read();
> 2. sent packet with "BBB" to TCP client, by write();

Now, when running this code, in tcpdump, I saw there are 2 TCP round trips:

> 1. Client --> Server, sent with "AAA"
> 2. Client <-- Server, ACK for "AAA"
> 3. Client <-- Server, Sent with "BBB"
> 4. Client --> Server, ACK for "BBB"

Question: how to write the code to make TCP server combine #2 and #3? That means TCP server replies client with ACK for "AAA" **and** attach data payload with "BBB".

**Update:**

I have a simple TCP server which just send the received 4 bytes back to client ("echo"). So it would be very quick (< 1 us). But I still see they are sent in 2 packets:

```
    192.168.4.171.44244 > 192.168.4.170.6001: Flags [P.], cksum 0xfd64 (correct), seq 679795                                                                                                  205:679795209, ack 1808420495, win 14600, options [nop,nop,TS val 216427 ecr 746617], length                                                                                                   4
        0x0000:  4500 0038 9770 4000 4006 18aa c0a8 04ab  E..8.p@.@.......
        0x0010:  c0a8 04aa acd4 1771 2884 da05 6bca 4e8f  .......q(...k.N.
        0x0020:  8018 3908 fd64 0000 0101 080a 0003 4d6b  ..9..d........Mk
        0x0030:  000b 6479 4141 4141                      ..dyAAAA
16:46:14.310817 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 10998, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 5                                                                                                  2)
    192.168.4.170.6001 > 192.168.4.171.44244: Flags [.], cksum 0x8acc (incorrect -> 0x8067),                                                                                                   seq 1808420495, ack 679795209, win 14480, options [nop,nop,TS val 746617 ecr 216427], lengt                                                                                                  h 0
        0x0000:  4500 0034 2af6 4000 4006 8528 c0a8 04aa  E..4*.@.@..(....
        0x0010:  c0a8 04ab 1771 acd4 6bca 4e8f 2884 da09  .....q..k.N.(...
        0x0020:  8010 3890 8acc 0000 0101 080a 000b 6479  ..8...........dy
        0x0030:  0003 4d6b                                ..Mk
16:46:14.310854 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 10999, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 5                                                                                                  6)
    192.168.4.170.6001 > 192.168.4.171.44244: Flags [P.], cksum 0x8ad0 (incorrect -> 0xfdd8)                                                                                                  , seq 1808420495:1808420499, ack 679795209, win 14480, options [nop,nop,TS val 746617 ecr 21                                                                                                  6427], length 4
        0x0000:  4500 0038 2af7 4000 4006 8523 c0a8 04aa  E..8*.@.@..#....
        0x0010:  c0a8 04ab 1771 acd4 6bca 4e8f 2884 da09  .....q..k.N.(...
        0x0020:  8018 3890 8ad0 0000 0101 080a 000b 6479  ..8...........dy
        0x0030:  0003 4d6b 4141 4141                      ..MkAAAA
16:46:14.310987 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 38769, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 5                                                                                                  2)
    192.168.4.171.44244 > 192.168.4.170.6001: Flags [.], cksum 0x7feb (correct), seq 6797952                                                                                                  09, ack 1808420499, win 14600, options [nop,nop,TS val 216427 ecr 746617], length 0
        0x0000:  4500 0034 9771 4000 4006 18ad c0a8 04ab  E..4.q@.@.......
        0x0010:  c0a8 04aa acd4 1771 2884 da09 6bca 4e93  .......q(...k.N.
        0x0020:  8010 3908 7feb 0000 0101 080a 0003 4d6b  ..9...........Mk
        0x0030:  000b 6479                                ..dy
```

**UPDATE AGAIN:**

After I set TCP socket option to disable TCP Quick ACK, I still did not get the combined packet replied:

```
opt = 0;   
setsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_QUICKACK, (char *) &opt, sizeof(opt));
```

Comment: Best thing you can do is omit the ACK. But: you'll need a timeout (which you'll need anyway) See for instance SMTP (rfc822) with the "200 Go ahead"; the server is just expecting data, no ack needed.

Comment: Why? It's not under your control, and the server might need some time to prepare the BBB response.

Comment: After I set TCP socket option to disable TCP Quick ACK, I still did not get the combined packet replied:
opt = 0;   
setsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_QUICKACK, (char *) &opt, sizeof(opt));